# How to pass the In-argument parameters of windows workflow to a custom code activity properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow-foundation-4

```
        //adding parameters and invoking workflow but the properties inside the codeactivity is all
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Activity workflow1 = new Workflow1();//activity
      IDictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
      parameters.Add("toFolder", @"C:\BackupByWorkFlow");//param1
      parameters.Add("fromFolder", @"C:\");//param2
       WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(workflow1, parameters);//invoke
    }

// workflow1 contains sequence of activities

// sequence->WhileBackup activity -> and  other custom activities

      //Custom code activity in workflow is as below
    public sealed class WhileBackup : CodeActivity
     {
       // Defining properties
           public InArgument<string> Text { get; set; }
            public InArgument<string> toFolder { get; set; }//property is null
            public InArgument<string> fromFolder { get; set; }//property is null
            public int totalFiles { get; set; }
            public int currentFile;
            public  FileInfo[] files;

        // If your activity returns a value, derive from CodeActivity<TResult>
        // and return the value from the Execute method.
          protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
                  {
                       // Obtain the runtime value of the Text input argument
                       string text = context.GetValue(this.Text);
                 }
    }
```

The in-argument value of workflow is not null but the same in code activity in the same workflow is null.hence I want to know how to pass the value of the in argument of workflow to the code activity property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters that you pass to Invoke are passed as arguments to the workflow but, they do not automatically trickle down to the activities in the workflow.

In the workflow definition, you have to define the arguments that you intent to pass to the workflow and you must explicitly map the toFolder and fromFolder arguments to the toFolder and fromFolder properties of the activity.

Note that the names of the arguments and properties do not have to match and making them match does not imply anything.